# I need to find a Folder on the Network Share

Tags: powershell

How can I find Folders called BlueMountain when this folder could be nested anywhere in my Users home folder

```
\\Server\Users\<personsname>\
```

Ultimately I want to delete the folder but just to be on the safe side. The BlueMountain folder must have one of these subfolder

```
Certs
Config
Macros
Scripts
Spool
Traces
Transfer
```

This is what I have so far

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\Server\Users -Recurse -Directory -Filter $_.FOLDERNAME | ForEach-Object {
        If $_.FullName --eq "BlueMountain" {

        }

    }
```

Comment: The `fullname` property of a file object returned by `Get-ChildItem` will contain the full path of the file. Your comparison will always return `$false`. Furthermore, the comparison operator is `-eq`, not `--eq`. Please do some more research and testing before coming to SO for help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `-recurse` to look for the last thing in your path recursively. So this:

```
Get-ChildItem \\server\Users\BlueMountain -recurse
```

Will look in all subfolders of "\server\Users" for anything named "BlueMountain". Then you just need to make sure it has one of your folders.

```
$SubFolders = 'Certs','Config','Macros','Scripts','Spool','Traces','Transfer'
Get-ChildItem \\server\Users\BlueMountain -recurse | Where{Get-ChildItem "$($_.FullName)\*" -Include $SubFolders}
```

That should list only the BlueMountain folders found recursively in \server\Users which contain one of the specified subfolders. Then you can just pipe that to `Remove-Item -force` and call it a day. Or if you want to track things pipe it to `tee-object` and then to `remove-item`.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$SubFolders = 'Certs','Config','Macros','Scripts','Spool','Traces','Transfer'
$wordtosearch="BlueMountain"
$SearchPattern= ($SubFolders | %{ "$wordtosearch\\$_" }) -join "|"

get-childitem "\\Server\Users" -directory -Recurse | 
    where FullName -match $SearchPattern | 
        Split-Path -path {$_.FullName} -Parent | 
            remove-item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```